# Black Screen after log-in in linux Mint 17 Cinnamon Qiana

Tags: linux

Installed Linux Mint 17 Cinnamon Qiana on my Toshiba Satellite M55. Every once in a while I get a Black Screen after I log-in and I all see is the Mouse pointer. I checked and double checked the Driver Manager but all I get is for the modem, nothing else.

Comment: Do you login always only after a cold boot or might this have to do with logout and then suspension of the machine (e.g. by closing the lid)? This question is a bit broad to give useful help. Would you have a possibility to login from another machine to the laptop to see what is going on (`sshd` running)?

Comment: Press `ctrl+alt+F2` and then `ctrl+alt+F7`
I am doing this for every boot in Ubuntu-14.04

Comment: Sorry. Yes, it happens on cold boot only. And like I said, it happens once in awhile. Log in screen comes up i log in and all I see is my mouse pointer, black screen.

Comment: It also sometimes freezes.